# How can I extract fieldNorm from Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene 3.6 and I want get score of each term in certain field of document for future use at search time. To store index I have created documents like this:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("description", entry.getDescription(), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
writer.addDocument(doc);
writer.close(true);
```

For example, document has a "football" term:

```
...
1.623904 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(description:football in 1775), product of:
1.0 = tf(termFreq(description:football )=1)
8.660821 = idf(docFreq=5, maxDocs=12741)
0.1875 = fieldNorm(field=description, doc=1775)
...
```

I'm using this code to get `tf` and `idf`:

```
TermFreqVector freqV = indexReader.getTermFreqVector(docId, "description");
for (int j = 0; j < freqV.getTerms().length; j++) {
    String term = freqV.getTerms()[j];
    int freq = freqV.getTermFrequencies()[j];
    float idf = similarity.idfExplain(new Term("descpription", term), searcher).getIdf();
}
```

but I can't understand how to get `fieldNorm` at search time.
Can anybody help with this question?

Thanks.